# A script runs via localhost but not via 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, ubuntu-16.04, cgi

I am trying to migrate some software from apache 2.2 to 2.4. I have it working - almost. When accessing the server via address `localhost` things work, but when trying to access via `127.0.0.1` some things don't.

For example, **http://localhost/cgi-bin/WI_facility** shows me the correct page, but **http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/WI_facility**  asks me do I want to `save the file WI_facility which is BIN file (164KB)`.

This happens on Ubuntu 16.04. On 17.04 and 17.10, both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` work normally.

Key part of the apache2.conf is below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
    <Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Why bother using virtual hosts when you aren’t even setting the `ServerName`? Might as well skip them altogether.

Comment: @DanielB: Afaik that's the recommended style nowadays, even for the "default" vhost.

Comment: @DanielB I took the default configuration script and modified it slightly, trying to reflect the effect of customization which was based on old default configuration.